# Function definition doesn't match its declaration in C but does in C++

Tags: c++, c, function-declaration

When there is no visible declaration or definition of `struct bar` in the following code, it compiles successfully as C++ but not as C:

```
void foo(struct bar* p);

void foo(struct bar* p){}

int main(){}
```

Error message when compiled as C: `error: conflicting types for 'foo'`.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

I have tried this with both [*clang++ 3.4*](http://rextester.com/ABRO9583) and [*g++ 4.8.2*](http://rextester.com/WHA51688) with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` flags and either `-std=c99` or `-std=c++03` for C and C++ respectively.

Comment: Is `struct bar` defined above, in between, or below these lines (or possibly not at all)?

Comment: @Jongware Not at all, of course.

Comment: Adding a definition for `struct bar` makes this error go away. Is your question "why is a not-defined type not equal to the same not-defined type"?

Comment: @Jongware Possibly it is. Possibly it is not. I don't know is it valid to use not-defined types in the same manner.

Comment: If your question is commented on or attracts down-votes or close requests, it is a hint to improve it!  There's a legitimate and interesting question here. If you are lucky, my edits have saved it from oblivion.  However you might want to check that I have not just changed the question.  BTW if two different, widely used and mature compilers do the same thing - a compiler bug is the least likely explanation; this one is clearly about the different semantics of the same code in C and C++.

Comment: @Clifford Thank you for your edit. But I think that it is important to include in the question the information about used compilers and its flags (`-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` is a usual set if you want to get the most standard-compliant behavior). And there are a lot of examples when two widely used compilers (such as *clang* and *gcc*) do the same and *incorrect* thing.

Comment: @Constructor : I have restored that information. But in the meantime the question got an up-vote ;-)  With respect to compiler behaviour, pragmatically speaking, corner cases of the standard and subtle semantic differences between C and C++ are best avoided where possible.  In this case both C and C++ compilation behave identically when a forward declaration or prior definition is used, and quality and maintainability and portability are best served that way in any case.  To be honest it would never have occurred to me to omit the declaration in either language.

Comment: What you did not mention in your question is all the previous C compilation warnings that rather explain the problem in C, leaving you only with the question about why C and C++ differ in this respect.  If you are going to ignore warnings, it rather makes `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors` a bit pointless; if you believe they are useful then you should perhaps commit fully to this quality effort and add `-Werror`?

Comment: @Clifford Yes, I usually forget `-Werror` flag, sorry. And thank you for your edits again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's simplify the program by omitting the declaration and the useless `main`:

```
void foo(struct bar* p){}
```

The compiler sees `struct bar`, which has not been defined. The error message from GCC 4.8.2 explains what it does next:

```
a.c:1:17: warning: ‘struct bar’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
 void foo(struct bar* p){}
                 ^
a.c:1:17: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
```

So now it assumes that `struct bar` is something that only exists within the definition of `foo`. The code compiles perfectly, though.

When you add the function prototype:

```
void foo(struct bar* p);

void foo(struct bar* p){}
```

the warning becomes:

```
a.c:1:17: warning: ‘struct bar’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
 void foo(struct bar* p);
                 ^
a.c:1:17: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want [enabled by default]
a.c:3:17: warning: ‘struct bar’ declared inside parameter list [enabled by default]
 void foo(struct bar* p){}
                 ^
a.c:3:6: error: conflicting types for ‘foo’
 void foo(struct bar* p){}
      ^
a.c:1:6: note: previous declaration of ‘foo’ was here
 void foo(struct bar* p);
      ^
```

So like before, the compiler makes up a new, undefined type `struct bar` for the prototype, and *another one* for the function definition. So the prototype for `foo` and its definition refer to different types, both named `struct bar`. They don't match, hence the error.

The solution is to first forward-declare the `struct`:

```
struct bar;

void foo(struct bar* p);

void foo(struct bar* p){}
```

This compiles without warnings.

Comment: OK. But why does the same code compile successfully with [*clang++ 3.4*](http://rextester.com/ABRO9583) and [*g++ 4.8.2*](http://rextester.com/WHA51688) (with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic-errors -std=c++03` flags)?

Comment: @Constructor Because C++ apparently has different rules for `struct` definition scope. Sorry, missed that bit in your question, and I can't quote the C++ standard for the rules.

Comment: There is no reason to apologize. I've added this piece of the question after your answer. It is sadly that you haven't a relevant quote from the C++ standard. But what about the C one?

Comment: @Constructor; C11 6.2.1 defines scope, especially p4 and p7 is relevant (_function-prototype scope_ is what you're after). I currently fail to find the part where it's mandated that the forward-declaration works (and `struct bar` in the prototype doesn't declare a new type and hide the outer definition), though.

Comment: @mafso : Surely it works in C++ is because the first use is an implicit forward declaration and there is only one declaration?  That being the case, there would not be an explicit mention regarding forward declaration overriding the implied declaration, because they were always the same.  As the C warning says the behaviour is *"probably not what you want"*, so in C++ it is fixed, probably because in C++'s design, compatibility with C was secondary to fixing some of C's semantic flaws.